# Urwid ListBox: How to get fluid focus movement?

Tags: python, user-interface, console, curses, urwid

I have the following code snippet that shows a list of numbers, and highlights the currently in-focus item:

```
import urwid

palette = [('header', 'white', 'black'),
    ('reveal focus', 'black', 'dark cyan', 'standout'),]

items = map(lambda x: urwid.Text(`x`), range(500))
items = map(lambda x: urwid.AttrMap(x, None, 'reveal focus'), items)

walker = urwid.SimpleListWalker(items)
listbox = urwid.ListBox(walker)

loop = urwid.MainLoop(listbox, palette)
loop.run()
```

When I start the program the terminal looks like:

```
0   <-- highlighted
1
2
3
...
```

If I press the `down` button then the view changes to:

```
1
2
3
4   <-- highlighted
...
```

I would like a behavior in which `0-3` are highlighted and in-focus before the screen scrolls downward. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items in the list box need to be selectable. Here is one approach:

```
class SelectableText(urwid.Text):
    ...
    def selectable(self):
        return True
...

items = map(lambda x: SelectableText(`x`), range(500))
```

Comment: This allows it to be selectable, but my impl still tells me that it needs a keypress has no keypress defined. I defined this, but making a Text work for ListBox still doesn't work even with a SimpleFocusListWalker

Answer (score 3):

The accepted solution fails on first key press:

```
AttributeError: 'SelectableText' object has no attribute 'keypress'
```

Injecting my own implementation that does nothing makes the error go away, but it also completely borks all keybindings.

I found this and it seems to work just fine:

```
class SelectableText(urwid.Edit):
    def valid_char(self, ch):
        return False
```